# Evaluating $ \int_{|z| = 2} \frac{\sin z }{(z-1)(z+3)^3} dz.$

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

I want to evaluate
$$ \int_{|z| = 2} \frac{\sin z }{(z-1)(z+3)^3} dz.$$
Here is my approach:
By a change of variables and using homotopy invariance, this should equal
$$ \int_{|z-1| = 1} \frac{\sin (z+1) }{z(z+4)^3} dz.$$
This looks almost like something that could be evaluated using the Cauchy Integral Formula, i.e.
$$ \int_{|z-1| = 1} \frac{\sin (z+1) }{z(z+4)^3} dz = \int_{|z-1| = 1} \frac{z^{-1}\sin (z+1) }{(z+4)^3} dz$$
can be viewed as a factor of the 3rd coefficient of the power series expansion of $z^{-1} \sin(z+1)$ around $-4$, which could then be easily evaluated by computing derivatives. The only problem is that $|z-1| = 1$ isn't a curve around the singularity $-4$. How can I change this?  I also feel kind of uncomfortable mixing change of variables with homotopy invariance, and would like to know whether my reasoning here is even correct in the first place.

Comment: There's no need for the change in variables. Simply rewrite your integrand as $\frac{\sin(z)/(z + 3)^3}{z - 1}$ and notice that $\frac{\sin(z)}{(z+3)^3}$ is analytic everywhere inside your curve (since $z = -3$ is exterior to your curve) and you can use CIF directly. (note that if $-3$ was interior to the curve, then you could simply use the Residue Theorem and add the residues from both poles)

Comment: That was more straightforward than expected. I would still be interested in knowing whether the rewriting I did was valid or not, though :)

Comment: As far as whether your rewriting is correct, to me it looks like you would have arrived at that integrand after the substitution $u = z - 1,$ which basically corresponds to a simple origin shift. That said I believe the correct domain of integration would then be $|u + 1| = 2,$ which is just the circle with radius $2$ now centered around $-1.$ I don't see how you would get the radius of $1.$ Perhaps I've missed some of your logic?

Comment: Shouldn't it be irrelevant whether I integrate around the circle of radius 2 vs. the circle of radius 1, since those two paths are homotopic?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the statement you're using, but surely you have to transform the integrand using the same transformation that you use for the path, don't you? Otherwise by your same logic couldn't I argue that the original integral must be $0$ by integrating on any circle with radius less than $1,$ so that all poles of the function were exterior to the curve?

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood something, but can't you deform the (closed!) path of integration freely (as a consequence of Cauchy's Integral Theorem), as long as you don't cross any singularities of the integrand?

Comment: For a meromorphic function like this, yes this makes sense. However I still don't see the point in doing so if we're still just going to use Cauchy's (or the Residue Theorem) in the end anyway, it just seems unnecessary. In any case, this specific rewriting is still not quite right because you've put the pole originally at $z = 1$ onto the path of integration itself, so I believe your rewritten integral simply doesn't exist.